# Mention the bot instead of prefix

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the commands to work when mention the bot instead of prefix, but I don't know how to do it. Please help me. Example: @bot ping

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `when_mentioned_or` method in the `commands` module when instantiating your bot:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("?"))
```

---

**Reference:**

- [`commands.when_mentioned_or()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or)

Comment: The prefix doesn't work when I try this     
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= get_prefix, case_insensitive=True)

Comment: And what's in your `get_prefix` function? Could you edit it into the question please, or use pastebin/hastebin.

Comment: get_prefix = custom prefix

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [this](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be) example to see how it's been implemented there.